# Should there be used two prepositions after a verb?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Now,I have an issue.
There is the preposition "away" in English and the phrasal verb - be away.

Which sentence below is correct -

```
I am away the meeting
I am away at the meeting ?
```

SHOULD I use either two preposition in this case or one is enough?

Comment: You need both, as in your second example.

Comment: @BillJ I've understood nothing.Where is both needed?

Comment: @BillJ , Please,sorry for my stupidity)I've realized I need both prepositions -  away and at.It's kind of you to help me,thanks).But,there is one more question,I'd like to ask.What about run away - He ran away out of the building?It's a little difficult using a few preposition in a row

Comment: @BillJ , One more example - I looked up the wall or I looked up at the wall?

Comment: @Sckoriy, I recommend making that comment (up the wall vs look up at the wall) its own question, as it needs a more detailed answer.

Comment: _Away_ is not a preposition: it is an adverb.